# Java - Maven Test/Unit Test passed when running the whole package but failed when running the test individually

Tags: java, maven, testing

I just received a project from my collage and when I run the whole project with Maven test/ Maven install by right click to the whole project and choose Maven test or Maven install, it runs successfully. However if I run an individual test, this test failed. I do not really understand here why it happened. Can anyone give me a hint please? Thank you!

Comment: one of the previous tests is setting something, probably a data base, so the tests are order dependent

Comment: Hi @EssexBoy, does it mean these tests are not unit tests, instead integration tests?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that another unit test is establishing some state that is affecting the unit test that is failing. It is best practice to avoid writing unit tests that depend on shared state, as there is usually no guarantee as to what order the tests run in. See [this article](http://www.kyleblaney.com/junit-best-practices/) for a good explanation of unit test best practices.